# How can I check whether a subnet IPv4 address is unused while IPv4 is switched off?

Tags: linux, networking, ipv4

I've found sources that suggest how I can find whether an IP address is available using `ping`, `arping` and `nmap`, but all of these solutions fail when IPv4 is switched off. I'd like to find a way of automatically detecting whether an IPv4 address is available before assigning it to a new machine that does not have an IPv4 address. For example,

```
$ sudo arping 192.168.2.205
ARPING 192.168.2.205
60 bytes from 00:50:56:91:a5:0d (192.168.2.205): index=0 time=730.931 msec
60 bytes from 00:50:56:91:a5:0d (192.168.2.205): index=1 time=362.976 msec
60 bytes from 00:50:56:91:a5:0d (192.168.2.205): index=2 time=730.205 msec
^C
--- 192.168.2.205 statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 3 packets received,  25% unanswered (0 extra)
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
$ sudo arping 192.168.2.205
arping: Unable to automatically find interface to use. Is it on the local LAN?
arping: Use -i to manually specify interface. Guessing interface eth0.
arping: Unable to get the IPv4 address of interface eth0:
arping: libnet_get_ipaddr4(): ioctl(): Cannot assign requested address
arping: Use -S to specify address manually.
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: or you could use dhcp and not worry about assigning ips at all...?

Comment: I can't use DHCP for this application. It's a device that needs to be installed on a network with a UI for manually assigning an IP address.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about software development; it probably belongs on [networkengineering.se]

Comment: it'd be chicken/egg. you'd probably have to implement something like bonjour and config the ip from an external app.

Comment: Yup, chicken and egg problem. ARP `who-has` requests let you ask if an IP is in use on the current subnet, but the reply must go to an IP address - so you'd need to already have an IP to use ARP.

Comment: @Jim, thanks for the pointer. That makes sense, but its not clear where the boundary is. I'm developing software for a networked device, and it'd be nice to include a server-side check when the user configures the ips (especially in the test environment where there's lots of churn in ip assignments).

Comment: Ask on [networkengineering.se] to figure out how to accomplish the task. Then if you have a problem with an API or algorithm in the implementation you can ask here.